# Spark2.1.0 incompatible Jackson versions 2.7.6

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jackson, sbt, incompatibletypeerror

I am trying to run a simple spark example in intellij, but I get the error like that:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:819)
at spark.test$.main(test.scala:19)
at spark.test.main(test.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.7.6
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:64)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:730)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
```

I have try to update my Jackson dependency, but it seems not work, I do this:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.8.7"
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.7"
```

but it still appear the same error messages, can some one help me to fix the error?

Here is spark example code:

```
object test {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    if (args.length < 1) {
        System.err.println("Usage: <file>")
        System.exit(1)
    }

    val conf = new SparkConf()
    val sc = new SparkContext("local","wordcount",conf)
    val line = sc.textFile(args(0))

    line.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_).collect().foreach(println)

    sc.stop()
    }
}
```

And here is my built.sbt:

```
name := "testSpark2"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"


libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.8.7"
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-repl_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-flume_2.10" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-network-shuffle_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-flume-assembly_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mesos_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-graphx_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-catalyst_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-launcher_2.11" % "2.1.0"
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Spark 2.1.0 contains `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` as transitive dependency. So, we do not need to include then in `libraryDependencies`.

But if you want to add a different `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` dependencies' version then you have to override them. Like this:

```
name := "testSpark2"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"


dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.8.7"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.7"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.8.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-repl_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-flume_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-network-shuffle_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-flume-assembly_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mesos_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-graphx_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-catalyst_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-launcher_2.11" % "2.1.0"
```

So, change your `build.sbt` like the one above and it will work as expected.

I hope it helps!

Comment: @hey_you: can you provide your `build.sbt` file?

Answer (score 8):

FYI. For my case, I'm using spark and `kafka-streams` in the app, while kafka-streams uses com.fasterxml.jackson.core 2.8.5. Adding `exclude`  as below fixed the issue

(gradle)

```
compile (group: "org.apache.kafka", name: "kafka-streams", version: "0.11.0.0"){
    exclude group:"com.fasterxml.jackson.core"
}
```

Comment: Were you having the exact same problem? Incompatible Jackson version?

Answer (score 1):

Solution with Gradle, by using the resolutionStrategy (https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html):

```
configurations {

    all {

        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.4', 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.4', 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.4'
        }
    }
}
```