# Check a code of Spark RDD using local REPL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I want to check my scala spark code by REPL.
This code works well in spark-shell, but local scala with sbt didn't work.
(After executing sbt in the command line, and execute console command to start REPL.)

What should I do?

**code**

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext  
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("RddSample").setMaster("local[*]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val data = (0 to 10).toArray
val inputRDD = sc.parallelize(data)
```

**error**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Scala module 2.9.4 requires Jackson Databind version >= 2.9.0 and < 2.10.0 at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:61)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:18)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:730)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:692)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:821)
... 40 elided
```

**build.sbt**

```
name := "Sratup"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
val sparkVersion = "2.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.9.4"
libraryDependencies +="com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.4"
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.9.4"
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.9.4"
```

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841091/spark2-1-0-incompatible-jackson-versions-2-7-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Spark version, (in fact, AFAIK, every version up from 2.1.0 )already includes `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` so you don't need to put them in your `build.sbt`.

If you want to use a different version of them you should remove them from `libraryDependencies` and include them in `dependencyOverrides`

```
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.9.4"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.4"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.9.4"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala" % "2.9.4"
```

You can check which dependencies the spark 2.3.0 includes [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.3.0)

Comment: I extracted the jackson*.jar from the jar folder of spark and copied it to the extended jar folder of sbt. This code works very well. Thank you so much!