# ExceptionInInitializerError Spark Streaming Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming-kafka

I am trying to connect Spark Streaming to Kafka in a simple application. I created this application by the example from the Spark documentation. When I try to run it I get such an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream.<init>(InputDStream.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.<init>(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:124)
    at producer.KafkaProducer$.main(KafkaProducer.scala:36)
    at producer.KafkaProducer.main(KafkaProducer.scala)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.9.4
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:64)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:751)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
```

Here is my code:

```
object KafkaProducer {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("KafkaSparkStreaming")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(3))
    val topics = Array("topic1", "topic2")

    def kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "1",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
    )

    val lines = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      ssc,
      LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
      ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
    )
    lines.map(_.key())

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I am not sure whether the problem is in configuration or the code itself.Tha's how my build.sbt file looks like:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.3.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.3.0"
)
```

I would be grateful for any help, cause I can not figure out what's wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By following the stack trace of the Exception you have faced with, we can find out the main problem is:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.9.4

As a matter of fact

> Spark 2.1.0 contains com.fasterxml.jackson.core as transitive dependency. So, we do not need to include then in libraryDependencies.

which is described more detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841091/spark2-1-0-incompatible-jackson-versions-2-7-6) for a similar problem and its solution.