# Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.8.9

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

When I do `df.show()` to print the content of DataFrame rows, I get this error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.8.9
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:64)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:747)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
```

This is how I create `df`:

```
object Test extends App {

   val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .config("es.nodes", "XXX.XX.XX.XX")
      .config("es.port", "9200")
      .config("es.nodes.wan.only", "false")
      .config("es.resource","myIndex")
      .appName("Test")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

   val df_source = spark
                   .read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
                   .option("pushdown", "true")
                   .load("myIndex")

   df_source.show(5)

}
```

I do not use Jackson library in my `build.sbt`.

**UPDATE:**

```
import sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin.autoImport.assemblyOption
name := "test"
lazy val spark = "org.apache.spark"
lazy val typesafe = "com.typesafe.akka"
val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"
val elasticSparkVersion = "6.2.4"
val scalaLoggingVersion = "3.7.2"
val slf4jVersion = "1.7.5"
val kafkaVersion = "0.8.0.0"
val akkaVersion = "2.5.9"
val playVersion = "2.6.8"
val sprayVersion = "1.3.2"
val opRabbitVersion = "2.1.0"
val orientdbVersion = "2.2.34"
val livyVersion = "0.5.0-incubating"
val scalaHttpVersion = "2.3.0"
val scoptVersion = "3.3.0"
resolvers ++= Seq(
  // repo for op-rabbit client
  "SpinGo OSS" at "http://spingo-oss.s3.amazonaws.com/repositories/releases",
  "SparkPackagesRepo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven",
  "cloudera.repo" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos"
)
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "org.test",
  version := "0.1",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
  assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = true),
  assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("reference.conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
  }
)
val sparkSQL = spark %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion
val sparkGraphx = spark %% "spark-graphx" % sparkVersion
val sparkMLLib = spark %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion
val elasticSpark = "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop" % elasticSparkVersion
val livyAPI = "org.apache.livy" % "livy-api" % livyVersion
val livyScalaAPI = "org.apache.livy" %% "livy-scala-api" % livyVersion
val livyClientHttp = "org.apache.livy" % "livy-client-http" % livyVersion
val spingoCore = "com.spingo" %% "op-rabbit-core" % opRabbitVersion
val spingoPlayJson = "com.spingo" %% "op-rabbit-play-json" % opRabbitVersion
val spingoJson4s = "com.spingo" %% "op-rabbit-json4s" % opRabbitVersion
val spingoAirbrake = "com.spingo" %% "op-rabbit-airbrake" % opRabbitVersion
val spingoAkkaStream = "com.spingo" %% "op-rabbit-akka-stream" % opRabbitVersion
val orientDB = "com.orientechnologies" % "orientdb-graphdb" % orientdbVersion excludeAll(
  ExclusionRule("commons-beanutils", "commons-beanutils-core"),
  ExclusionRule("commons-collections", "commons-collections"),
  ExclusionRule("commons-logging", "commons-logging"),
  ExclusionRule("stax", "stax-api")
)
val scopt = "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % scoptVersion
val spray = "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % sprayVersion
val scalaHttp = "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % scalaHttpVersion

lazy val graph = (project in file("./app"))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(sparkSQL, sparkGraphx, sparkMLLib, orientDB,
                                livyAPI, livyScalaAPI, livyClientHttp, scopt,
                                spingoCore, scalaHttp,
                                spray, spingoCore, spingoPlayJson, spingoJson4s,
                                spingoAirbrake, spingoAkkaStream, elasticSpark)
  )
dependencyOverrides += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % akkaVersion
```

I tried to add Jackson libraries for Spark, but it didn't solve the problem:

```
val jacksonCore = "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.6.5"
val jacksonDatabind = "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.6.5"
val jacksonAnnotations = "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" %% "jackson-annotations" % "2.6.5"
val jacksonScala = "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.6.5"
```

Finally, I did this (the last two dependencies cannot be resolved for some reason):

```
dependencyOverrides += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % akkaVersion
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.8.9"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.9"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.8.9"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.8.9"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-paranamer" % "2.8.9"
```

But now I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/DefaultScalaModule$
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$
```

Comment: what version of Spark are you using? are you using Scala 2.11? can you share your build.sbt file?

Comment: @Mikel: Please see my update. I use Spark 2.2.0, Scala 2.11.8 and Elastic-Hadoop 6.2.4.

Comment: How do you build your Spark app? I noticed you use sbt-assembly plugin. How do you run the app? Could `dependencyOverrides` help as described in https://stackoverflow.com/q/43841091/1305344?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: Please see my update. I also tried

Answer (score 7):

jackson version for Spark 2.2.0 is 2.6.5, it looks like one of your other dependencies is using jackson 2.8.9, these two versions are not compatible so you need to align them to the same jackson version.

This build.sbt looks very problematic since you have mixed a lot of thing that probably don't align in jackson and with other dependencies.

For example op-rabbit-json4s is expecting jackson to be 3.5.3, on the other hand I think that orientdb-graphdb is expecting a third version of jackson (2.2.3)

In summary, you need to align as much as possible your dependencies to make sure there are no concflicts.

Here you can find a useful plugin to check dependencies https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph

Comment: Anyone who's looking currently; putting `addDependencyTreePlugin` in your plugins somewhere is the equivalent to this answer.